# MATLAB math operation with the power function is giving me very off results (giving me extremely small numbers)

Tags: matlab, math, plot, operation

I wrote the following code to plot a graph. The math operation for `value` does not make sense.

I have captured a screenshot. It looks like this.

[image: here].

The new_x and new_y values are repectively -3 and 5.0249 in this iteration, but the 'value' calculated is some absurdly small number.

I tried the exact same thing in the command window using the same inputs and it works fine...

```matlab
for i = 1:length(x_vals)
    syms f(y);
    f(y) = 3 * x_vals(i)^(7) + 2 * y^(5) - x_vals(i)^(3) + y^(3);
    df = diff(f,y);
    
    f_func = matlabFunction(f(y));
    f_prime = matlabFunction(df);
    a = 4;
    tolerance = 10.^-6;

    root(i) = Newton(f_func, f_prime, a, tolerance);
    %value(i) = G(x_vals(i),root(i));
    
    new_x = double(x_vals(i));
    new_y = double(root(i));
    
    value = 3 * new_x^7 + 2 * new_y^5 - new_x^3 + new_y^3;
    
    if (value >= -3 - e && value <= -3 + e)
        y_vals(i) = root(i);
        z_vals(i) = -3;
    end
end
```

Comment: When did you take that screen shot? Did you stop the program in the debugger? Did you stop if *after* value is calculated?

Comment: @Galina. I am wondering if this is part of a script? in which I case I suspect that the vlalue of `value` in the screen shot is from a previous run and you haven't evaluated the `value= .3*new_x^7 ...` . where is the break point?